# Is it possible to make default drawer not floating in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm now working on a flutter project.

I have to use drawer in this case, but as for the design, I need the drawer to be non-floating like the default was. How can I achieve this using the default Drawer widget? I'm trying to use plugins as less as possible.

It should be looks like this:

[image: drawer design]

Instead of this:

[image: default drawer image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible by using default `drawer` property. What you can do is use `SlideTransition` in `Scaffold`'s `body`.

Comment: Ah, I see, I'll take a look of it. Thank you.. :)